# Alterar cor de acordo com a batida da música

Tags: javascript, canvas, áudio

Estou criando um Player de música e preciso que as barras de frequência mudem de cor conforme as batidas mais fortes.
Eu consegui fazer isso https://codepen.io/salomaosnff/pen/eezgVL porém, está muito rápido.

Comment: Podes explicar melhor _"porém, está muito rápido"_?

Comment: Veja a partir da linha 130, minha tentativa foi fazer a média de `dataArray` e verificar se está ultrapassando certo valor(105). Mas não está funcionando como eu espero que é de uma maneira mais lenta, somente nas batidas mais fortes.